# Sending Two or more chars using SendInput

Tags: c++, winapi

To send a char, we can use SendInput. How can I use it to send more than one char?

I tried this code but it does not send anything:

```
INPUT in;
in.type=INPUT_KEYBOARD;
in.ki.wScan=0;
in.ki.time=0;
in.ki.dwExtraInfo=0;
in.ki.wVk=0x53+0x54;

SendInput(2,&in,sizeof(INPUT));
```

So, what is the right way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first parameter of `SendInput()` specifies how many `INPUT` structures you are passing in.  You are only passing in 1, but you are telling `SendInput()` that you are passing in 2.

You cannot specify two separate virtual keys in a single `INPUT`.  You need to declare an array of multiple `INPUT`s, 2 `INPUT`s for each virtual key - one for the keydown event, and one for the keyup event.  So, in your example, you actually need 4 `INPUT`s to send 2 virtual keys, as shown in @user4581301's answer.

Now, regarding `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`, you don't use virtual keys with it, you use actual Unicode codepoints instead, where they are specified using UTF-16 codeunits, one per `INPUT`.  So that means if you want to send a Unicode codepoint that requires a UTF-16 surrogate pair, you need 2 sets of down/up `INPUT`s, one set for the high surrogate, and one set for the low surrogate.  That caveat is *NOT* mentioned in the `SendInput()` documentation, but it is implied by the fact that the `vScan` field is a 16bit `WORD`, and that `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` events generate `WM_CHAR` messages, which passes UTF-16 surrogate codeunits as separate messages.

So, to send a string of Unicode characters using `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`, you can do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void SendInputString(const std::wstring &str)
{
    int len = str.length();
    if (len == 0) return;

    std::vector<INPUT> in(len*2);
    ZeroMemory(&in[0], in.size()*sizeof(INPUT));

    int i = 0, idx = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        WORD ch = (WORD) str[i++];

        if ((ch < 0xD800) || (ch > 0xDFFF))
        {
            in[idx].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            in[idx].ki.wScan = ch;
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
            ++idx;

            in[idx] = in[idx-1];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            ++idx;
        }
        else
        {
            in[idx].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            in[idx].ki.wScan = ch;
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
            ++idx;

            in[idx].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            in[idx].ki.wScan = (WORD) str[i++];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
            ++idx;

            in[idx] = in[idx-2];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            ++idx;

            in[idx] = in[idx-2];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            ++idx;
        }
    }

    SendInput(in.size(), &in[0], sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I've got you right, you want something more along the lines of this:

```
INPUT in[4] = {0}; // four inputs

// first input 0x53
in[0].type=INPUT_KEYBOARD;
in[0].ki.wScan=0;
in[0].ki.dwFlags=0;
in[0].ki.time=0;
in[0].ki.dwExtraInfo=0;
in[0].ki.wVk=0x53;

in[1] = in[0];
in[1].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

// second input 0x54
in[2].type=INPUT_KEYBOARD;
in[2].ki.wScan=0;
in[2].ki.dwFlags=0;
in[2].ki.time=0;
in[2].ki.dwExtraInfo=0;
in[2].ki.wVk=0x54;

in[3] = in[2];
in[3].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(4,in,sizeof(INPUT));
```

Probably want to wrap the grunt work setting up the INPUT structure into a function to reduce duplication.

Comment: that dosnt work, even if it works, that would be so hard to send a variable string

Comment: @Kordy, it does work, when used correctly (this answer was *partially* correct - it was sending two inputs for keydown events, but was not sending two additional inputs for the corresponding keyup events - I have corrected that). As for variable-length strings, you would simply allocate the `INPUT` array dynamically at runtime based on how many characters are actually in the string, and then populate the array with each character. And when sending strings, you are better off using the `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag to send actual UTF-16 characters instead of sending virtual key codes,

Comment: @RemyLebeau could you give me an example of using KEYEVENTF_UNICODE flag?

Comment: @Kordy: I posted an answer demonstrating `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`.

Answer (score 0):

Other answer didn't seem to work in a DirectX game. I tested the following in TrackMania Nations and it worked correctly: (notepad etc work as well)

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

void press_some_keys (std::string str) {
    INPUT input[2 * (int)str.size()] = {0};

    int cnt = 0;
    for (char ch: str) {
        input[cnt].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input[cnt].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
        input[cnt].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(LOBYTE(VkKeyScan(ch)), 0);
        cnt++;

        input[cnt] = input[cnt - 1];
        cnt++;
    }

    SendInput(2 * (int)str.size(), input, sizeof(INPUT));
    Sleep(10);

    for (cnt = 1; cnt < 2 * (int)str.size(); cnt += 2)
        input[cnt].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    SendInput(2 * (int)str.size(), input, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

I only tested lowercase alphabet characters (no arrows or others), but it was enough for me.

It was a pain to get it working since the closest thing I found was a single tap function in a Youtube video :-)