# SendInput sends wrong Unicode character in MFC

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, sendinput

I have a simple SendChar function:

```
void SendChar(const char mC)
{
    INPUT ip={0}; KEYBDINPUT kb={0};
    char mK=mC;

    kb.wScan=mK;
    kb.dwFlags=KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    ip.type=INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki=kb;
    SendInput(1,&ip,sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

It run good with normal key but when I want to sends a unicode character example 'á' (0xE1 in unicode table), it sends wrong character ('￡').

```
SendChar(0xE1);
SendChar('á');
```

But it successes with this

```
void SendChar()
 {
      INPUT ip={0}; KEYBDINPUT kb={0};

      kb.wScan=0xE1;
      kb.dwFlags=KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
      ip.type=INPUT_KEYBOARD;
      ip.ki=kb;
      SendInput(1,&ip,sizeof(INPUT));
  }
```

Please help me know what wrong with my first function?

Comment: You are trying to send UTF-8 but MS-Windows is UTF-16.  So all you are sending is extended ASCII not Unicode.

Comment: Thanks Richard, Can you show me how to send unicode key in my app?

Comment: change `void SendChar(const char mC)` to `void SendChar(const wchar_t mC)` and pass it a UTF-16 Unicode character.  Try `SendChar(L'￡');`

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked!

Comment: Note that Unicode characters outside of the BMP do not fit in a single `wchar_t`.  You should change `SendChar()` to accept a `wchar_t*` or `std::wstring` string instead, calling `SendInput()` with an array of `INPUT`s for each `wchar_t` (not counting the null terminator). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38625599/65863.