# Using a string with the SendInput Function on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard, sendinput

I want to use a `std::string` for the [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) function.

After doing some research, I found that the [`VkKeyScanEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-vkkeyscanexa) might help but the code needs additional logic for uppercase or special characters. In the latter case I realized that I can simulate a <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key press, send the lowercase key input and then it would come out as uppercase. However, there are also the "special" characters like `!"§$%&/()=?` which need a held down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key to come out correctly. Furthermore, there are also the umlauts like `äüö`. My code below works but the umlauts are also capitalized which is wrong for example (because [`isalnum()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalnum) returns true for those as well). Isn't there a reasonable way of handling any string input and simulating it via the user's keyboard regardless of region, language and so on without causing such a logical mess? Isn't there a simpler and foolproof way to do this?

```
const auto key_board_layout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

void configure_input(INPUT& input)
{
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input.ki.wScan = 0;
    input.ki.time = 0;
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
}

void send_input(const HWND window_handle, const std::string& message)
{
    SetForegroundWindow(window_handle);
    std::locale::global(std::locale("")); // Needed to not crash on certain special characters      

    for (auto character : message)
    {
        INPUT key_input;
        configure_input(key_input);

        INPUT shift_input;
        configure_input(shift_input);
        shift_input.ki.wVk = VK_SHIFT;

        // Type the key
        const auto virtual_key = VkKeyScanEx(character, key_board_layout);
        key_input.ki.wVk = virtual_key;
        const auto is_shift_key_required = isupper(character) || !isalnum(character);
        if(is_shift_key_required)
        {
            // Hold down the shift key
            SendInput(1, &shift_input, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
        SendInput(1, &key_input, sizeof(INPUT));

        // Release the key
        key_input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, &key_input, sizeof(INPUT));

        if(is_shift_key_required)
        {
            // Release the shift key
            shift_input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            SendInput(1, &shift_input, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`. Also, you must not call `SendInput` one event at a time. Assemble all the events into an array, and send them in a single atomic call to `SendInput`. After all, that is pretty much the entire reason for the existence of `SendInput`.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38625599/65863) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622583/), and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307429/65863) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305404/), for code examples of using `SendInput()` with `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` and `std::wstring`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @RemyLebeau: Your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38625599/3764804 worked. :)

Comment: The combination of `SetForegroundWindow` and `SendInput` usually means, you should be using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) instead.