# How to make SendInput use fixed (en-US) layout regardless of what layouts the user have installed or uses?

Tags: c++, winapi, sendinput

I find it quite handy that I can use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) to mix text and controls into single string and send it to any application like
`"\nHello\nWorld"` would end up with sequence of

```
hit {Enter}
type "Hello"
hit {enter}
type "World"
```

In any chat application (for example).

I have the following code

```
void GenerateKey(WORD vk)
{

    INPUT Input;
    ZeroMemory(&Input, sizeof(Input));
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki.time = 0;
    Input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    Input.ki.wVk = vk;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    return;
}

void SendKeys(const LPCWSTR format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    WCHAR buffer[256];
    vswprintf_s(buffer, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    BlockInput(true);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<wcslen(buffer); ++i)
        GenerateKey((WORD)VkKeyScan(buffer[i]));
    BlockInput(false);
}
```

It works pretty fine. But the problem is, it depends on the currently used layout of the keyboard.

I have also tried to use [LoadKeyboardLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadkeyboardlayouta), but the following has no effect at all

```
    BlockInput(true);
    HKL keyboard_layout = LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", KLF_ACTIVATE);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<wcslen(buffer); ++i)
        GenerateKey((WORD)VkKeyScanExW(buffer[i], keyboard_layout));
    BlockInput(false);
```

I also welcome any ideas to achieve the goal.

[SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) isn't an option, cause it would require me to get a handle to the window and also to the text box.

Comment: Uhh `(LPCWSTR)0x409` does not look at all like [MSDN's examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadkeyboardlayoutw).

Comment: @chris quote from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadkeyboardlayoutw) page
> "For example, U.S. English has a language identifier of 0x0409, so the primary U.S.". Did I get it wrong?

Comment: "so the primary U.S. English layout is named `"00000409"`". It also says at the very beginning that it expects a name, not a pointer whose value bytes form an ID.

Comment: @chris OMG yes you were right :) :) silly me. I got the latter working, but it still doesn't work as expected. Still sends Russian chars instead of English while I have Russian layout on my machine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say I'm familiar with the workings of input locales or how `SendInput` is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `SendInput()` with `cInputs==1` is (almost) always a bug in user code. Don't do it!  One of the main benefits of using `SendInput()` over `keybd_event()` is the ability to *atomically* submit an array of inputs at one time (so no need for using `BlockInput()` at all).

In this case, create an array of `INPUT`s for the keystrokes, and then call `SendInput()` only 1 time.  And, per the [`KEYBDINPUT` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagkeybdinput), `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` doesn't take virtual key codes as input, it takes actual Unicode text characters instead (which means you don't have to deal with keyboard layouts manually).

You are also not sending `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` events at all.  You need those, even when using `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE`.

See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307429/65863) to [Sending Two or more chars using SendInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305404/) for more details.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void SendInputString(const std::wstring &str)
{
    int len = str.length();
    if (len == 0) return;

    std::vector<INPUT> in(len*2);
    ZeroMemory(&in[0], in.size()*sizeof(INPUT));

    int i = 0, idx = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        WORD ch = (WORD) str[i++];

        if ((ch < 0xD800) || (ch > 0xDFFF))
        {
            in[idx].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            in[idx].ki.wScan = ch;
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
            ++idx;

            in[idx] = in[idx-1];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            ++idx;
        }
        else
        {
            in[idx].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            in[idx].ki.wScan = ch;
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
            ++idx;

            in[idx].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            in[idx].ki.wScan = (WORD) str[i++];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
            ++idx;

            in[idx] = in[idx-2];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            ++idx;

            in[idx] = in[idx-2];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            ++idx;
        }
    }

    SendInput(in.size(), &in[0], sizeof(INPUT));
}

void SendKeys(LPCWSTR format, ...)
{
    std::wstring buffer;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    buffer.resize(_vscwprintf(format, args) + 1);
    buffer.resize(vswprintf_s(&buffer[0], buffer.size(), format, args));

    va_end(args);

    SendInputString(buffer);
}
```