# Reading UTF-8 file, passing contents to other application using SendInput

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I have a utf-8 formatted file that contains a character '`ů`', when I read it in c++ using ifstream and cout it, the output is '`┼»`'. I can solve it by adding '`SetConsoleOutputCP( 65001 );`', afterwards Im sending the char using '`SendInput();`' to another window. But because the SetConsoleOutput() doesnt affect SendInput() the application recieves the corrupted character '`┼»`'.
The question is how to SendInput() accented character?

```
        ifstream file(path);
        string str;
        while (getline (file, str)) 
        {
            cout << endl << str <<endl;
            for (char &c : str) {
                INPUT ip;
                ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                ip.ki.wScan = 0;
                ip.ki.time = 0;
                ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
                ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
                if (isupper(c)) {
                    ip.ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;
                    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
                } else {
                    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                    ip.ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;
                    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
                    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
                } 
                ip.ki.wVk = VkKeyScanA(c);
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
                Sleep(100);
            }
            INPUT enter;
            enter.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            enter.ki.wScan = 0;
            enter.ki.time = 0;
            enter.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
            enter.ki.dwFlags = 0;
            enter.ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
            SendInput(1, &enter, sizeof(INPUT));
            cout << "enter pressed";
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223354/discussion-on-question-by-johny-incognito-reading-utf-8-file-passing-contents-t).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the UTF-8 data to UTF-16 first, such as with `MultiByteToWideChar()` or equivalent, and then you can pass the individual UTF-16 codeunits to `SendInput()` using the `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307429/65863) to [Sending Two or more chars using SendInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305404/) for an example of sending UTF-16 strings with `SendInput()`.

Answer (score 2):

1. UTF-8 and Windows are not good friends. Almost everything you are going to do with Windows requires UTF-16. You need to convert your UTF-8 string to UTF-16. On Windows, that would be "wstring", but you should use the right conversion routine. Alas the C++ standard cannot be bothered to give you a working one one right now, so Windows-specific `MultiByteToWideChar` seems like a good option.
2. ```
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    if (isupper(c)) {
                ip.ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;
   ```

   It doesn't work this way.

   > If the dwFlags member specifies KEYEVENTF_UNICODE, wVk must be 0.

   Unicode characters cannot be combined with Shift or other modifiers. They are not key codes, they are characters. `A` and `a` are different characters, there is no need to send shift presses to differentiate between them. You also don't need `VkKeyScanA`, because you want to send Unicode characters, not scan codes.