# Check whether character needs Shift key to be pressed

Tags: c++, windows, character

I'm trying to write a program, that can write text to an input field (by simulating key presses). For that I need to be able to know whether <kbd>Shift</kbd> needs to be pressed in order to write a specific character. The `isupper(char)` method works great, but doesn't give the desired result when asking for stuff like a question mark, slashes, or similar characters.

```cpp
isupper('?') -> false
```

Is there any method that tells me if I need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> in order to write a specific character?

Comment: There is an easier way.  If you are using `SendInput()` to simulate text input (which you should be), it has a `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag available that you can use to send characters as-is, then you don't need to simulate Shift at all.

Comment: Thanks. If it is really that easy I will be sure to try it out!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307429/65863) for an example

Comment: Nice thanks it works.