# winuser.h keyboard input char to hex convertion

Tags: c++, windows, integer, hex

I've been searching and testing this for a while now and haven't found an answer to the problem i have.

What i'm trying to do is make my own kind of library for mouse and keyboard simulated keypress. I'm trying to do this for a fun little project where i can automate some tasks that are impossible to integrate with any other way. Simulating a user this way would be handy.

My problem lies with keyboard key presses. to be more precise here's an example code for pressing the letter 'a' on the keyboard:

```cpp
    INPUT inputs[2] = {};
    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = 0x41;

    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = 0x41;
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(inputs), inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
```

This works fine. So i tried to make it into a variable:

```cpp
void keyboardKeyPress(char key)
{
    INPUT inputs[2] = {};
    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = key;

    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = key;
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(inputs), inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

This also works fine. BUT **as soon as** i iterate through a string using this function, it outputs something weird. i tested this with the string "hello" and it outputs "85/". Here's the code i'm using:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>

using namespace std;

void keyboardKeyPress(char key)
{
    INPUT inputs[2] = {};
    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = key;

    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = key;
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(inputs), inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
}

void keyboardType(const string str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        keyboardKeyPress(str[i]);
    }

}

int main()
{
    keyboardKeyPress(65);
    keyboardKeyPress(66);
    keyboardKeyPress(' ');
    keyboardType("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs "ab 85/". I tried to do many things. i realised you can use hex codes instead of chars because the .ki.wVk actually wants unsigned short's. it works when you plug the values in statically but as soon as you try to get the hex values from an eg unsigned short array, it goes back to displaying "85/". The array:

```cpp
WORD ascii[] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
    0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F,
    0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27,
    0x28, 0x29, 0x2A, 0x2B, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x2F,
    0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37,
    0x38, 0x39, 0x3A, 0x3B, 0x3C, 0x3D, 0x3E, 0x3F,
    0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47,
    0x48, 0x49, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x4D, 0x4E, 0x4F,
    0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57,
    0x58, 0x59, 0x5A, 0x5B, 0x5C, 0x5D, 0x5E, 0x5F,
    0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67,
    0x68, 0x69, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x6D, 0x6E, 0x6F,
    0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77,
    0x78, 0x79, 0x7A, 0x7B, 0x7C, 0x7D, 0x7E, 0x7F
};
```

The array index is basically the ascii integer number and the value stored is the unsigned short (or WORD from winuser). And here's the changed function:

```cpp
void keyboardKeyPress(char key)
{
    INPUT inputs[2] = {};
    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = ascii[int(key)];

    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = ascii[int(key)];
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(inputs), inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Comment: Don't include `<winuser.h>`, it's automatically included by `<windows.h>` (which in normal cases is the *only* Windows header file you need to include).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions don't work as expected because [ASCII codes](https://www.asciitable.com) are not [Virtual Key codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes), though there is *some* overlap but not the way you think.

The <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> keys on the keyboard  are represented by virtual key codes `VK_A`  (65/0x41) and `VK_B` (66/0x42), respectively. They also happen to be the same values as the ASCII codes for the `'A'` and `'B'` characters, not the `'a'` (97/0x61) and `'b'` (98/0x62) characters.

When typing on a keyboard, uppercase and lowercase letters are differentiated  by whether the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (virtual key code `VK_SHIFT`, 16/0x10) is held down or not.

Since you are not simulating the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key being held down, that is why `keyboardKeyPress(65)` and `keyboardKeyPress(66)` are outputting `a` and `b`.

However, the ASCII code for the `'h'` character (104/0x68) is the same value as the virtual key code `VK_NUMPAD8`. The <kbd>H</kbd> key on the keyboard is represented by virtual key code `VK_H` (72/0x48) instead.

The `'e'` character is ASCII code 101/0x65, aka virtual key code `VK_NUMPAD5`, not `VK_E` (69/0x45).

The `'l'` character is ASCII code 108/0x6C, aka virtual key code `VK_SEPARATOR` (which does not represent any ASCII character) , not `VK_L` (76/0x4C).

The `'o'` character is ASCII code 111/0x6F, aka virtual key code `VK_DIVIDE`, not `VK_O` (79/0x4F).

That is why `keyboardType("hello")` is outputting `85/`.

Also, your `ascii[]` array is useless, because it is simply mapping the character codes back to their original values as-is, not to the proper virtual key codes.

So, to fix your code, you would have to get rid of the `ascii[]` array, and instead add additional logic to "hold down" the `VK_SHIFT` virtual key for an uppercase letter if it is not currently down, and "release" it for a lowercase letter if it is currently down. And then things get more complex if you need to deal with languages that have non-ASCII characters, etc.

That said, simulating textual characters is much easier if you use the `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag. Use virtual key codes only for non-textual keys. And you should send the entire string as one atomic unit instead of sending each character individually (injecting multiple events atomically into the event queue is one of the key features of `SendInput()` over `keybd_event()`). See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307429/65863) for an example of using `SendInput()` with strings.