# win32 send unicode to application

Tags: winapi

In win32, we can send raw keypresses via SendInput. Now WinCompose can send arbitrary unicode strings to an application as input. How do I do this with win32 (that is, for example, to send an emoji to an application as if input from the keyboard like happens with WinCompose)?

Comment: If you need to automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: `SendInput()` can also send Unicode characters, via its `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307429/65863 for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remy Lebeau's comment has the answer: `SendInput()` can also send Unicode characters, via its `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31307429/65863 for an example

The code is copied below:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void SendInputString(const std::wstring &str)
{
    int len = str.length();
    if (len == 0) return;

    std::vector<INPUT> in(len*2);
    ZeroMemory(&in[0], in.size()*sizeof(INPUT));

    int i = 0, idx = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        WORD ch = (WORD) str[i++];

        if ((ch < 0xD800) || (ch > 0xDFFF))
        {
            in[idx].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            in[idx].ki.wScan = ch;
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
            ++idx;

            in[idx] = in[idx-1];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            ++idx;
        }
        else
        {
            in[idx].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            in[idx].ki.wScan = ch;
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
            ++idx;

            in[idx].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            in[idx].ki.wScan = (WORD) str[i++];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
            ++idx;

            in[idx] = in[idx-2];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            ++idx;

            in[idx] = in[idx-2];
            in[idx].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            ++idx;
        }
    }

    SendInput(in.size(), &in[0], sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Comment: We are appreciating that you are satisfied with the help Remy Lebeau provide. If your case has been solved, please help to mark answer and this will be beneficial to other community.